# Check html element's click event fired programmatically or by clicking with mouse

Tags: jquery

I must check which is fired the click event, click with mouse or .click() function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that like this...

```
$('button').on("click", function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) {
        // the button was actually clicked
    } else {
        // the button was triggered by code
    }
});
```

Comment: Has the same problem mine does, that Kevin B pointed out: Calling `click` on the actual DOM element tricks it.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't aware of that and have used this myself in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell by looking at the `pageX` or `pageY` property of the event object, which will be `undefined` if `$("some selector").click();` was used, but a number if an actual mouse click occurred. For example:

```
(function($) {

  $("#target").click(function(e) {
    if (typeof e.pageX === "undefined") {
      display("Fired programatically");
    }
    else {
      display("Fired by real click");
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#target").click();
  }, 500);

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/azaday/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/azaday/1/edit)

Of course, if someone gets really clever and builds a full click event *including* fake `pageX` and `pageY` information, that won't work, but jQuery's default handling of `$("some selector").click();` doesn't do that.

Comment: This of course doesn't catch `.click()` being called directly on the dom node (in chrome atleast). http://jsbin.com/azaday/2/edit due to lack of context, i have no idea if this is important to the question.

Comment: @KevinB: Lovely, Chrome (at least) supplies `0` for `pageX` and `pageY`. But I bet we could find *something* on the event object that's different...